# Can I move an Indexer, or its contents?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forestry, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I want to move my bee indexer. Is there a way of doing so easily? Is there anything easier than piping bees through tesseracts or an ender chest? The gravity gun can't pick it up.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114047/can-i-break-my-apiarists-chest-without-my-bees-spilling ? They should probably be merged, and the question title changed to "How can I move a lot of stored bees?" Unless of course there something special about Indexers that makes it especially challenging!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It is a different, albeit related question, and the answer to that one isn't so good for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just used a couple of ender chests, with wooden pipes and autarchic gates to pull the bees out of the indexer. It took a little while but was relatively easy.

The only downside is I had to build another indexer rather than reuse the old one, but they're not that expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving it with the Portal Gun or the Gravity Gun, but those guys are a bit picky about what they move. You could also try using RedPower2 frames.

Comment: I can't get the Gravity Gun to pick it up. How do I move things with the Portal gun?

Comment: if the gravity gun doesnt work chances are the portal wont either, your best bet then would be frames. if you need to move a long distance its probably more trouble.

I suggest making an aapiarist backpack to pick up all the bees that get dropped from your indexer. and then you'll just have to put them back in manually once you have the new location.

Comment: Breaking indexers crashes servers, I don't think that's the best way.

Comment: then your only option to move it would be redpower frames, but I dont know how reliable or stable that will be.

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer to include your comments; as it stands right now it's a bit threadbare...