# Can I break my apiarist's chest without my bees spilling?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forestry

I'm moving houses, and I want to move the apiarist's chest without things being spilled. How can I accomplish this? I cannot pick it up with the Gravity Gun.

Comment: long pipe, item tesseract, enderchest, AE drives,...

Comment: @ratchetfreak Why AE drives?

Comment: the storage cells can be moved and store 64 different bees at the time

Comment: @ratchetfreak The chest can store more.

Comment: I meant for the movement, you pump a bunch in the system and move the drive over and empty it on the other side,

Comment: @ratchetfreak Oh, you could do that, but then you'd need import and export buses, and I'm not made of resources.

Comment: This title makes so little sense to me, yet reminds me of Nick Cage. "NOT THE BEES!!!" +1 Sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an apiarist's bag (from extra bees I think), it can hold as many bees as the apiarist's chest, and can be carried around.

Put the bag into receiving mode and shift-click the chest with the bag in your hand. This sucks all the bees into the bag. Move the chest and then shift-click again in any other mode to empty the bag into the chest.

Comment: Excellent. It does exactly what I want.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ You couldn't have done it that fast.

Comment: You could also break the chest and suck in all the bees.